# Principle of mathematical induction to prove well ordering principle for set of rationals.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

I am not being able to find what is wrong in this proof.

statement: For any set of rationals there is a least element in the set.

Hypothesis: $p(k)$=For set of k rationals there exist a least element in the set.

now,

It is trivial to prove that p(1) and p(2) are true.

Now suppose $p(k)$ is true.
For Every set of k rationals there is a least element in the set.

Now we check truth value of $p(k+1)$ .

as we can split set $k+1$ of rationals as set of $k$ and 1 rational.

Now , as we know both of them have least element hence least among them will be least element in the set.

Hence,$$p(k)\implies P(k+1)$$ and Hence, Using PMI we prove that any set of rational elements has a least element .

Which is not true for rationals belonging in (0,1).

Comment: So, you're proving that every **finite** set of rationals has a least element.

Comment: NO, any countable set of rationals has a least element.

Comment: @ShubhamUgare Consider the set of all rationals greater than zero - which is countable because the rationals are.

Comment: when I prove something using mathematical induction it doesnt mean that it is true for p(k) such that k is finite It means it is true for all k belonging to natural numbers, right?

Comment: @ShubhamUgare NO, what the proof you gave actually _proves_ is just that every finite set of rationals has a smallest element. You proved by induction on $k$ that if $S$ is a set of rationals and $S$ has $k$ elements then $S$ has a smallest element. Every $S$ in sight is finite.

Comment: All $k$ belonging to the natural numbers are finite.

Comment: To reiterate in a slightly different way what has been said already here: the natural numbers contain an infinite *amount* of elements. But *each* element is finite. The size of each set in your proof is some natural number, which is finite. So you are only proving this for all finite sets- even thought the *amount* of these sets is infinite.

Comment: @ColmBhandal Each element is finite?

Comment: @SolidSnake I was being a bit ambiguous. There are two meanings to what I said really. On the one hand, any number is finite in size, syntactically. E.g. we can represent it with a finite number of digits in base 10. On the other hand, the *meaning* of a natural number, when interpreted as a cardinality, represents a finite cardinality. The latter is more related to this question.

Comment: Can anyone help me. what induction hypothesis will I use if I want to prove well ordering principle for set of naturals(can be infinite set) using only weak form of mathematical induction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're proving is that every **finite** set of rationals has a least element, that's why it doesn't work in the set $\Bbb Q\cap (0,1)$.

Notice your argument works even if the set is not from the rationals but from a totally ordered set.

You think that you've proved it for any countable subset of $\Bbb Q$, but, if this were true, you'd have proved it for **any subset of $\Bbb Q$** since $\Bbb Q$ is countable by itself.

Please keep in mind that induction can only prove statements about *finite* things, but *any* finite number of them. For example, you can prove by induction that for every **finite** set of natural numbers, there is always a 'biggest' element, it doesn't matter the set has $1000$ or $10^{10^{100}}$ elements, but this fails to happen if the set is infinite.

Comment: So does that mean well ordering principle on set of naturals is valid only for finite sets of natural numbers?

Comment: No, that's a different matter. The proof of the well-ordering principle doesn't use induction in the way you've used it here. See this link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358979/proving-the-so-called-well-ordering-principle

Comment: how does the proof of the well-ordering principle use induction?

Comment: @miniparser Explain your question please.